# Circular Slider in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, slider, geometry

I'm hoping to get a round slider into ActionScript, very similar to what [**this page**](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/drag_vr.html) shows:

[image]

It's going to ultimately be altering the hue of an object (returning a CMY value), however if it just spits out the degree I can totally work with that. If you know of any resources, tutorials, pseudocode, or a snippet with this functionality, I would hugely appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is my solution to this problem.

It's worth noting that angles in Flash are handled in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) instead of degrees, which is why you'll notice the conversion methods in the code.  Personally, I find setting angles in degrees much easier to visualize and understand, which is why the *CircleSlider* constructor accepts a value in degrees and why the *CircleSliderEvent* class dispatches both degrees and radians.

**Use Case:**

```
var circleSlider:CircleSlider = new CircleSlider(100, 270);
circleSlider.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
circleSlider.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
circleSlider.addEventListener(CircleSliderEvent.CHANGE, circleSliderEventHandler);

addChild(circleSlider);

function circleSliderEventHandler(event:CircleSliderEvent):void
{
    trace(event.degrees, event.radians);
}
```

**CircleSlider Class:**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    //Class
    public class CircleSlider extends Sprite
    {
        //Properties
        private var mRadius:uint;
        private var mAngle:Number;
        private var mThumb:Sprite;

        //Constructor
        public function CircleSlider(radius:uint, degrees:Number)
        {
            mRadius = radius;
            mAngle = degrees;

            init();
        }

        //Init
        private function init():void
        {
            createCircle();
            createThumb();
            positionThumb(degreesToRadians(mAngle));
        }

        //Create Circle
        private function createCircle():void
        {
            var circle:Shape = new Shape();
            circle.graphics.lineStyle(4.0, 0xFFDDDD, 1.0);
            circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, mRadius);

            addChild(circle);
        }

        //Create Thumb
        private function createThumb():void
        {
            mThumb = new Sprite();
            mThumb.graphics.beginFill(0xFF2222, 1.0);
            mThumb.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
            mThumb.graphics.endFill();

            mThumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownEventHandler);

            addChild(mThumb);
        }

        //Mouse Down Event Handler
        private function mouseDownEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            mThumb.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEventHandler);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpEventHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseUpEventHandler);
        }

        //Enter Frame Event Handler
        private function enterFrameEventHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            positionThumb(Math.atan2(mouseY, mouseX));
        }

        //Mouse Up Event Handler
        private function mouseUpEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            mThumb.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEventHandler);

            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpEventHandler);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseUpEventHandler);
        }

        //Position Thumb
        private function positionThumb(radians:Number):void
        {
            mThumb.x = Math.cos(radians) * mRadius;
            mThumb.y = Math.sin(radians) * mRadius;

            mAngle = radiansToDegrees(radians);

            dispatchEvent(new CircleSliderEvent(CircleSliderEvent.CHANGE, mAngle, radians));
        }

        //Degrees To Radians
        private function degreesToRadians(degrees:Number):Number
        {
            return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        //Radians To Degrees
        private function radiansToDegrees(radians:Number):Number
        {
            return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
        }

        //Set Angle
        public function set angle(degrees:Number):void
        {
            positionThumb(degreesToRadians(degrees));
        }

        //Get Angle
        public function get angle():Number
        {
            return mAngle;
        }
    }
}
```

**CircleSliderEvent Class:**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.events.Event;

    //Class
    public class CircleSliderEvent extends Event
    {
        //Constants
        public static const CHANGE:String = "change";

        //Properties
        public var degrees:Number;
        public var radians:Number;

        //Constructor
        public function CircleSliderEvent (type:String, degrees:Number = NaN, radians:Number = NaN) 
        {
            super(type);

            this.degrees = degrees;
            this.radians = radians;
        }

        //Clone
        public override function clone():Event
        {
            return new CircleSliderEvent (type, degrees, radians);
        }

        //To String
        public override function toString():String
        {
            return formatToString("CircleSliderEvent", "type", "degrees", "radians");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is nothing short of astounding, and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so very much!