# get angle from a circle actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, geometry, actionscript-2

I found this answer ([Circular Slider in ActionScript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220832/circular-slider-in-actionscript-3)) which creates a drag-able point over a circle..In the answer there is the code in the CircleSlider class .

```
    private function mouseUpEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        mThumb.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEventHandler);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpEventHandler);
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseUpEventHandler);

        trace(mAngle);           
    }
```

when i put the trace code it shows the angle when i slide the point on the circle..i want to get that angle to a text box in main script.(frame script).can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use text property of your TextField object. Something like this: TEXT_FIELD_NAME.text = String(mAngle); 
If you use 1 frame and the textfield obj is into this frame you can use this keyword otherwise you must address right frame/place that contains the textfield object.

Comment: var text1:TextField = new TextField();
text1.text=String(mAngle);
addChild(text1);
I used above code.
it gives me an error saying "type was not found, or was not a compile time constant" Any idea??

Comment: The code is ok, maybe you must import the package use this: import flash.text.TextField;

Comment: Its working  thank you so much. can i ask one more thing ..how can i draw lines from x axis and y axis to point i click .(http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/trigonometry.htm plz refer this website.there is a playing flash file.) i managed to draw a line which shows the radius..how can i draw the other two red lines(in that website)..can you guild me?

Comment: This two lines are paralel to coord system  axis x and y So if your coordinate system have canter at Cx, Cy, and your point have coords Px and Py in this system than axis paralel to x has to be drawn from (Cx,Py ) to (Px,Py) , and for other line (Px,Cy) - (Px,Py). Don't forget to use localToGlobal and globalToLocal methods if you use different clips